# How to get the text from div class?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to read the text from div class from HTML page.
What I am trying is, I am trying to read text from below div classes.

```
<div class="Oprice clearfix">
<div class="text-bold Nprice">
```

I don't get it, what is clearfix and text-bold. please explain me.
The following code is working for both div classes.

```
Element lcEl = doc.getElementsByClass("Oprice").first(); //first div
System.out.println("found price: "+lcEl.text()); 

Element lcEl = doc.getElementsByClass("Nprice").first(); //second div
System.out.println("found price: "+lcEl.text());
```

but why below code not working?

```
Element lcEl = doc.getElementsByClass("Oprice.clearfix").first(); //first div
    System.out.println("found price: "+lcEl.text());

Element lcEl = doc.getElementsByClass("text-bold.Nprice").first();
    System.out.println("found price: "+lcEl.text());
```

please help me, is there any way to get it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using jsoup.

According to the method `getElementsByClass(String className)` that you have used does not allow multiple class names

```
public Elements getElementsByClass(String className)
```

This method finds elements that have this class, including or under this element. Its case insensitive. Elements can have multiple classes (e.g. `<div class="header round first">`. This method checks each class, so you can find the above with `el.getElementsByClass("header");`. But you cannot provide class name like `Oprice.clearfix`. Because its implementation doesn't allow that kind of argument.

> Parameters: className - the name of the class to search for.
>
> Returns: elements with the supplied class name, empty if none

If you want catch elements with multiple classes use `select()`,do it as follows,

```
String html = "<div class=\"content-text right-align bold-font\">foo</div>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = document.select("div.content-text.right-align.bold-font");
System.out.println(elements.text());
```

Comment: Not working for me i have below HTML <div class="_1t6k"><span class="fcg">This is for test</span></div>

Answer (score 1):

"Oprice" and "clearfix" are two classes for

```
<div class="Oprice clearfix"/>
```

which means, you can get this tag via:

```
doc.getElementsByClass("Oprice").first();
```

or

```
doc.getElementsByClass("clearfix").first();
```

the not working code:

```
doc.getElementsByClass("Oprice.clearfix").first()
```

just don't make sense. document.getElementsByClass() accepts a string denoting a class you want to query. The argument you provided ("Oprice.clearfix") looks like (but is not) a css query. You need to provide the **exact and accurate** class name in this method.

Comment: Thanks Wang Yu for your great explanation.

Comment: I have a similar situation. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223069/how-to-get-values-from-div-data-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223069/how-to-get-values-from-div-data-attribute) @saveendra-ekanayake - Can you please help